# How to provide const interface with iterators to a collection?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, constants

I would like to create a function with a signature like this:

```
// Set found to be an iterator to the location of key in map or end()
// if not found.
bool lookup(const Key &key,
            const std::map<Key, Value> &map,
            std::map<Key, Value>::const_iterator &found);
```

But I would like to also call it in cases where the map and iterator are not const so that I can modify the found value:

```
const Key key;
std::map<Key, Value> map;
std::map<Key, Value>::iterator found;

if (lookup(key, map, found)) {
  found->second.modifingNonConstFunction()
}
```

But I do not believe I can pass a `std::map<Key, Value>::iterator` object to a function expecting a reference to a `std::map<Key, Value>::const_iterator` since they are different types, whereas I normally could if the `const` was part of C++ declaration of the type like this and I could promote the non-const type to a const type:

```
void someFunction(const int &arg);

int notConstArg = 0;
someFunction(nonConstArg);
```

Other than by using templates to provide two definitions for `lookup()`, one as shown with `const` arguments 2 and 3 and another with non-const arguments 2 and 3, is there a better way in C++ to accomplish this more akin to how `const int &` can be passed a non-const `int` in the example above.  In other words, can I just have a single function and not two?

Comment: 1) Is there a reason you're not simply **returning** the iterator? (although I appreciate that won't solve this problem)  2) Your `int` example won't be able to modify the underlying `int`...

Comment: I clarified the question to show why.  I'm returning a bool value which when false, there is no guarantee that the iterator is valid.  In other words, the computation of the iterator may be skipped if return value is false.

Comment: The part I don't like about using end() instead of false is that I have to construct a dummy map to get end() because I really have a two level map: map<key1, map<key2, value> > so the return is an iterator to the inner map, but the outer lookup may fail, but to return end, I'd have to construct a dummy inner map to get an end() for it.  Unless there is a better way to get end()?

Comment: actually, you can't get away with this kind of const/non const even if you use pointers (const char *& versus char *&)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think you can do this without overloads/template magic.

The compiler is protecting you from the following scenario:

```
typedef vector<int> T;

const T v;  // Can't touch me

void foo(T::const_iterator &it) {
    it = v.begin();  // v.begin() really is a const_iterator
}

int main() {
    T::iterator it;
    foo(it);
    *it = 5;   // Uh-oh, you touched me!
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the function is simple or you don't mind binary bloat, just make every parameter a template parameter.

```
template <typename Key, typename T, typename Iter>
bool lookup(Key const& key,
            T& map,
            Iter &found)
{
  return (found=map.find(key))!=map.end();
}

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> m; m["hello"] = 42;
  std::map<std::string, int> const cm(m.begin(), m.end());

  std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it;
  std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator cit;

  std::cout << std::boolalpha << lookup("hello", m, it) << '\n'; // Key isn't even std::string
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << lookup("hello", m, cit) << '\n';
  //std::cout << std::boolalpha << lookup("hello", cm, it) << '\n'; // error
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << lookup("hello", cm, cit) << '\n';
}
```

This works since `T` can be both, `map` and `const map` so `T&` is `map&` or `const map&`.